# React Native cameraRoll save video to device from URL

Tags: react-native, camera-roll

I want to save video to a device from a URL.
I tried:

```
CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(videoURL, 'video')
```

and also:

```
CameraRoll.save(videoURL, {type: 'Video', album: 'Test'})
```

I'm getting this error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error -1.)

What's going wrong?

Comment: Please explain briefly what is 'not working' with sample output or expected output.

Answer (score 1):

While you fetch the file via RNFetchBlob.fetch. Pass appendExt : 'mp4' or 'mov' as config parameter alongside fileCache : true. This should fix your problem.
Also, type:'video' and not 'Video'.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing link CameraRoll into Xcode.